# Which highest normal form is this table in?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

```
Ticket Vname Nname
1      Oli   Seitz
1      Andi  Hofmann
2      Oli   Seitz
2      Oli   Schmidt
2      Tim   Schmidt
3      Tim   Hofmann
```

This table represents a mapping of persons (`Vname, Nname`) and tickets (`Ticket`). `Vname` and `Nname` together identify a person, but every Person (`Vname, Nname`) can have multiple tickets (`Ticket`), and a ticket can be assigned to multiple people.

The PK in this table are all three columns together. So this table should be 1NF because there is no multi dimensional data in one column.

But then I struggle. I think it is 2NF and 3NF because I can´t find any functional dependencies. (Hope they are called functional in English as well as in German)

Can someone explain which highest NF this table is and why? And what would I have to change to make it in 5NF?

Note: This is not homework, this question emerged from a discussion.

Comment: Hi. So what *defintions* of these terms are you using, and what do you get when you apply them? If you don't have definitions in mind, you are just using strings of letters and your sentences don't mean anything. You don't need a SO Q&A to get definitions.

Comment: @whymatter By the time I saw the question, the answer was already accepted.
This is a trick-question, your data-sample is carefully crafted (by you?) to
appear that it is possible to decompose the table into three projections,
which results in a logical error in the accepted answer. Inserting a single
row `(1, 'Tim',  'Seitz')` into the table invalidates the accepted reasoning.
The question is did you know this?

Comment: Good point, after reading more about NF5 I found this also. But as the question asks about this tables NF I let it the accented one.

Comment: @whymatter nothing really changes, the logical error does not go away. You may consider differentiating between `relation-variable` aka `relvar` (table) and the `relation-value`.

Comment: The *value* is decomposable. There is no error in my answer. Applying my answer to a *variable*: *All* values so decomposable gives not 5NF & *not* all values so decomposable gives 5NF. So *if that row can be inserted* then the variable is in 5NF; *otherwise we don't know whether it's in 5NF*. And *if it's not in 5NF* then that value *can't* be inserted; *otherwise we don't know whether it can be inserted*. But the question *does not say either way re either condition*. The other answer exhibits unsound arguing from vague & wrong informal "theorems"; mine correctly uses math & *definitions*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1NF (First Normal Form)**

["1NF" has no standard meaning.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097)

Since by definition a relation has one value per column per row, notions of "multi dimensional data in one column" don't make sense. Feel free to ask people to make sense. Feel free to ask them how whatever they do mean matters.

**Normalization to higher NFs (normal forms)**

The only thing that normalization to higher NFs has to do with "1NF" is that they are both trying to simplify to improve designs.

Your relation satisfies no non-trivial FDs (functional dependencies). So it is in **BCNF**.

Your relation satisfies no non-nontrivial MVDs (multi-valued dependencies). Ie it satisfies no non-trivial binary JDs (join dependencies). Ie it is not the join of the members of any pair of its projections other than a pair that includes itself. So it is in **4NF**. You can see this by taking pairs of projections and joining them. You can also do it by applying definitions of FD & MVD and identifying them, then applying the rules of inference for them.

Your relation satisfies the non-nontrivial JD `*{{Ticket, Vname}, {Vname, Nname}, {Ticket, Nname}}`. So it is the join of the members of a set of its projections other than a set that includes itself. But that JD is not implied by its CKs. Ie there is no chain of joins of its projections where every join's common attributes includes a CK of the original. So it is not in **5NF**. You can see this by taking sets of projections and joining them. There is no algorithm to determine what non-trivial JDs a relation satisfies with complexity better than brute force.

**Relation Meanings/Predicates**

On the other hand, suppose you *knew the relation's meaning* to the extent that you knew that it holds tuples that make a true statement from a *(characteristic) predicate* expressible as the conjunction of others, say

```
    ticket Ticket was submitted by a person with first name Vname
AND there is a person with name Vname Nname
AND ticket Ticket was submitted by a person with last name Nname
```

Join is designed so that the predicate of its output is the AND of the predicates of its inputs. So you would know to check for whether any corresponding decompositions of the original satisfy the JD (ie whether the relations from the conjuncts are projections of the original) and so to check whether the JD is implied by the original's CKs.

The point of normalization to higher NFs is that a JD holds when a relation's predicate can be expressed as the conjunction of others and their relations are projections of the original, so we can use the simpler separate relations instead, except we might as well JOIN/AND the relations/predicates on pairwise shared CKs because there are still no update anomalies. (If FD `{x, ...} -> a` holds then a certain MVD holds & a certain binary JD holds and the predicate of the relation can be expressed as `... AND a = f(x, ...)`.)

Note that contrary to claims that 5NF is to reduce update anomalies, it turned out that they disappear as of ETNF which lies between BCNF & 5NF. But a 5NF design is still simpler in the sense that there are fewer relations at the cost of adding ANDs to predicates. Note that MVDs & JDs that hold are hard to find *only because designs with them are intuitively obviously bad so they never get proposed, because their predicates are the conjunction of others*. Thus contrary to claims that 5NF is unimportant because violating JDs are rare, 5NF is the only NF that matters. (SQL systems don't support dealing with all the integrity constraints that can arise from 5NF designs, so that and ignorance leads to claims that one should settle for 3NF.)

You need to find *definitions* of the NFs and *why they matter*.

More re [predicates & the relational model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097).

(I only answered this question because received wisdom, even in textbooks, is such a mess.)

---

**Appendix**

Projections & joins. (I was going to leave the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to you. But the JD holding was disputed by another answerer so [here is an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fb025/25).)

```
T
1      Oli   Seitz
1      Andi  Hofmann
2      Oli   Seitz
2      Oli   Schmidt
2      Tim   Schmidt
3      Tim   Hofmann

project Ticket, Vname (T)
1      Oli
1      Andi
2      Oli
2      Tim
3      Tim

project Vname, Nname (T)
Oli   Seitz
Andi  Hofmann
Oli   Schmidt
Tim   Schmidt
Tim   Hofmann

project Ticket, Vname (T) join project Vname, Nname (T)
1      Oli   Seitz
1      Oli   Schmidt
1      Andi  Hofmann
2      Oli   Seitz
2      Oli   Schmidt
2      Tim   Schmidt
2      Tim   Hofmann
3      Tim   Schmidt
3      Tim   Hofmann

project Ticket, Nname (T)
1      Seitz
1      Hofmann
2      Seitz
2      Schmidt
3      Hofmann

     project Ticket, Vname (T) join project Vname, Nname (T)
join project Ticket, Nname (T)
1      Oli   Seitz
1      Andi  Hofmann
2      Oli   Seitz
2      Oli   Schmidt
2      Tim   Schmidt
3      Tim   Hofmann
```

Comment: I would argue that that JD discussed in 5NF does not hold. It is not possible to split FirstName and LastName of a person. The 5NF (any NF) is not defined over a sample data in a table but over any possible valid (future) values that may be entered in the table. Given that it is not possible to decompose the table and reduce redundancy, the table is in 5th NF. Key is {FirstName, LastName, Ticket}; the 5th NF table is all key,  hence is in the 6th NF. The predicate is: `Person (FirstName, LastName) is assigned ticket number (Ticket).` This is a simple predicate, can not be split.

Comment: I would also argue that "brute force" method does not hold, for it is possible, and necessary to determine a NF of an an empty table. All that is needed is predicate and constraints (keys, FD, JD).

Comment: The original is the join of the three 2-column projections, into which it can be decomposed, as I show in the appendix. Of course a *variable* would have to satisfy the JD in every state, but in the context of the one *value* in the post I am addressing whether *it* satisfies the FD. It doesn't matter that the predicate you give is appropriate, the predicate I gave is too. Anyway we *don't know* the predicate, it wasn't given. I used one with conjunctions to make the point that ANDs invite investigation. I mention "brute force" to informally capture that finding all JDs that hold is NP-hard.

Comment: Er, no. The predicate and constraints are included in the first paragraph, just below his example. Your analysis is very technical -- and it reveals a great deal of knowledge and expertise -- but the final conclusion is not correct.

Comment: This value violates 5NF because the binary projections join to the original. Which is true iff the conjuction of their predicates--exists Vname T(...),  Ticket T(...) & exists Nname T(...)--has the same truth value for all tuples as T(...). If the predicate was what I said, which is a typical situation, then in the state in which this value arose those three predicates would be equivalent to ticket Ticket was submitted by a person with first name Vname
AND there is a person with name Vname Nname, etc, respectively.

Comment: Charitably the predicate "ticket Ticket is assigned to person Vname Nname" can be inferred from the 1st paragraph. But I expect the wording is intended re table tuples & isn't trying to express a predicate in terms of the application. The paragraph does say something about how the table *isn't* constrained, ie about some FDs that don't hold. It does not say that there are no constraints. Obviously if the point of the paragraph was to say that there were no constraints at all then the variable would be in 5NF because it wouldn't satisfy any constraints so it wouldn't satisfy any JDs.

Comment: Suggest you add the charitable offering to the answer :) Without reading the comments, it appears you incorrectly conclude the highest normal form is 4NF but it seems this is based on the OP's misstatement (understatement?) I think most readers will conclude `Person (FirstName, LastName)` is implied in context, which a quick conversation with the customer would I'm sure have confirmed.

Comment: @onedaywhen I would agree that my answer would be improved by explicitly addressing both value & variable cases of NFs. Re "readers will conclude Person(FirstName, LastName) is implied in context", the question's 1st paragraph clearly states that Person(FirstName, LastName) for rows in the table. But that by itself has no effect on what NFs the table is in as value or variable. What my last comment points out is that the paragraph *is poorly written* although presumably the obvious guess is what they were *trying* to say.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate is:

`[p1]` Person named (FirstName) (LastName) is assigned ticket number (Ticket).

Constraints:

- `(c1.1)` *Person is identified by first name and last name.*
- `(c1.2)` *Ticket is identified by ticket number.*
- `(c1.3)` *For each person, that person may be assigned more than one ticket.*
- `(c1.4)` *For each ticket, that ticket may be assigned to more than one person.*

```
PersonTicket {FirstName, LastName, Ticket}
         KEY {FirstName, LastName, Ticket}
```

**NF Reasoning:**

1. The table is all-key, hence it is in the BCNF.
2. It is in the BCNF, it is not possible to reduce redundancy by decomposition, hence it is in the 5th NF.
3. It is in the 5th NF and all key, hence it is in the **6th NF**.

Note that the reasoning about NF does not require any data, it must be valid for an empty relational variable (table) and any possible valid values that the table may hold.

Also note that the predicate `[p1]` is a simple predicate, it generalises simple (elementary) facts, which is a telltale sign of the 6th NF. For example, the fact "`Person named Oli Seitz is assigned ticket number 1.`"
can not be split into two sentences without losing information.

---

**EDIT**

It has been a long discussion (see comments), so I have to expand the answer a bit.

My basic premise is that the table `{Ticket, Vname, Nname}` can not be decomposed into projections, or technically speaking that join dependency:

```
JD *{{Ticket, Vname}, {Vname, Nname}, {Ticket, Nname}}
```

*does not* hold. (note: Vname = first name, Nname =last name).

So let's take a closer look at this. What would it mean for the JD to hold? The JD can be verbalized as :

> IF *a person with a first name is assigned a ticket number* AND *a
>   person with a last name is assigned that ticket number* AND *there
>   exist a person with that first name and that last name* THEN *that
>   person with that first name and that last name is assigned that ticket
>   number*.

As you first read this, it may feel right, -- for a minute or two -- but is *plain wrong*.

Take a look at the example:

```
     Original       |             Three Projections
                    |
(T,  First,  Last ) | (T, First)  (First,   Last )  (T,   Last )
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
(1, 'Tom', '.....') | (1, 'Tom')  ('Tom', '.....')  (1, '.....')
(1, '...', 'Jones') | (1, '...')  ('...', 'Jones')  (1, 'Jones')
(2, 'Tom', 'Jones') | (2, 'Tom')  ('Tom', 'Jones')  (2, 'Jones')
```

Note that join of tuples

```
(1, 'Tom) ('Tom', 'Jones') (1, 'Jones')
```

produces an extra tuple

```
(1, 'Tom', 'Jones')
```

which is not in the original; hence the JD *does not hold*.

To put it loosely, a person identifier `(First, Last)` is split. So, person's first name and last name are acting independently of each other; a severe *logical error*.

It seems that the sample data in the original question was carefully crafted to appear the JD holds;
the original data-sample will pass this test. However, insert just one tuple (row) in the original table:

```
(1, 'Tim',  'Seitz')
```

Now test again, this one generates *two extra tuples* when joining projections:

```
(1, 'Tim', 'Hofmann')
(2, 'Tim', 'Seitz')
```

---

In the reasoning section I have used terms like: *simple predicate, elementary fact, information, identifier, and reducing redundancy*. In the comments below these have been labelled as: *fuzzy non-technical, unsound, wrong, vague, irrelevant, and nonsensical*.

It is interesting that these fuzzy, vague, nonsensical, etc. terms lead to the correct result, as opposed to a "precise, highly technical, (algorithm assisted ?)" method which can result in *severe logical errors*.

So, for those who would like to take a closer look at these -- IMHO extremely useful and practical -- terms, I can suggest a few references.

**`[1]`** About *simple predicates* and *6th NF*:

C. J. Date; Database Design and Relational Theory;
Part III, Chapter 13, Sixth Normal Form

**`[2]`** About *elementary facts*:

Terry Halpin, Tony Morgan; Information Modeling and Relational Databases;
Chapter 3, Conceptual Modeling: First Steps

Terry Halpin, What is an Elementary Fact?, paper 1993.

**`[3]`** About *5th NF and reducing redundancy*:

> "*To say that relvar R is in 5th NF is to say further non loss
>   decomposition of R into projections may be possible, but it won't
>   eliminate any redundancies.*"
>
> "*5NF guarantees freedom from redundancies that can be removed via
>   projection.*"
>
> C. J. Date; Master Class (video): Database Design and Relational Theory;
>  
>   Normalization JDs and 5NF (formal)-Part 2 of 2

**`[4]`** About *predicates and propositions*:

Part I, Chapter 2, Predicates and Propositions
Part V, Chapter 15, Database Design is Predicate Design
in : C. J. Date; Database Design and Relational Theory.

> *"Conceptually, the database is a set of sentences expressing
>   propositions taken to be true of the UoD."*
>
> Terry Halpin, Tony Morgan; Information Modeling and Relational Databases;
>   Chapter 2, Information Levels and Frameworks

---

#### EDIT 2

And finally, here is some code (PostgreSQL) to test.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_0 (
  Ticket integer  NOT NULL
, Vname  text     NOT NULL
, Nname  text     NOT NULL

, CONSTRAINT pk_tbl PRIMARY KEY (Ticket, Vname, Nname)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_0 (Ticket, Vname, Nname)
VALUES
  (1, 'Oli',  'Seitz')
, (1, 'Andi', 'Hofmann')
, (2, 'Oli',  'Seitz')
, (2, 'Oli',  'Schmidt')
, (2, 'Tim',  'Schmidt')
, (3, 'Tim',  'Hofmann')
;
```

The following query generates three projections, joins them together and shows the difference between the original table and joined projections. In other words, does join dependency
`JD *{{Ticket, Vname}, {Vname, Nname}, {Ticket, Nname}}` hold?

```sql
WITH
p_1 AS ( -- projection {Ticket, Vname}
    SELECT DISTINCT Ticket, Vname FROM tbl_0
),
p_2 AS ( -- projection {Vname, Nname}
    SELECT DISTINCT Vname, Nname FROM tbl_0
),
p_3 AS ( -- projection {Ticket, Nname}
    SELECT DISTINCT Ticket, Nname FROM tbl_0
),
j_pro AS ( -- join projections
    SELECT Ticket, Vname, Nname
    FROM p_1
    JOIN p_2 USING (Vname)
    JOIN p_3 USING (Ticket, Nname)
),
d_0 AS ( -- tbl_0 - j_pro
    SELECT Ticket, Vname, Nname FROM tbl_0
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Ticket, Vname, Nname FROM j_pro
),
d_1 AS ( -- j_pro - tbl_0
    SELECT Ticket, Vname, Nname FROM j_pro
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Ticket, Vname, Nname FROM tbl_0
)
-- diff = (tbl_0 - j_pro) union (j_pro - tbl_0)
SELECT Ticket, Vname, Nname FROM d_0
UNION
SELECT Ticket, Vname, Nname FROM d_1

ORDER BY Ticket, Vname, Nname
;
```

In the first run, all looks ok -- appears that the JD holds, no difference:

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| ticket | vname | nname   |
+--------+-------+---------+
```

However it's a trick question, the example was carefully crafted to produce this result. All it takes is adding one more row to reveal the problem:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_0 (Ticket, Vname, Nname)
VALUES (1, 'Tim', 'Seitz');
```

And now we get two extra tuples (run the query again).

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| ticket | vname | nname   |
+--------+-------+---------+
| 1      | Tim   | Hofmann |
| 2      | Tim   | Seitz   |
+--------+-------+---------+
```

To make it clear here is the table and the join of the three projections.

```
-- Added one more row (1, Tim, Seitz)
+--------+-------+---------+
| ticket | vname | nname   |
+--------+-------+---------+
| 1      | Andi  | Hofmann |
| 1      | Oli   | Seitz   |
| 1      | Tim   | Seitz   |
| 2      | Oli   | Schmidt |
| 2      | Oli   | Seitz   |
| 2      | Tim   | Schmidt |
| 3      | Tim   | Hofmann |
+--------+-------+---------+


-- JOIN {{Ticket, Vname}, {Vname, Nname}, {Ticket, Nname}}
-- generates two extra rows
-- (1, Tim, Hoffman) and (2, Tim, Seitz)
+--------+-------+---------+
| ticket | vname | nname   |
+--------+-------+---------+
| 1      | Andi  | Hofmann |
| 1      | Oli   | Seitz   |
| 1      | Tim   | Hofmann |
| 1      | Tim   | Seitz   |
| 2      | Oli   | Schmidt |
| 2      | Oli   | Seitz   |
| 2      | Tim   | Schmidt |
| 2      | Tim   | Seitz   |
| 3      | Tim   | Hofmann |
+--------+-------+---------+
```

Bottom line, the JD does not hold, the original table `{Ticket, Vname, Nname}` can not be decomposed into projections and is in **6th** NF as stated in the first part of this -- too long by now -- answer.

---

#### Final Thoughts

And finally, what does it take to determine NF of a relational variable (table in 1NF)? The usual answer is: heading, functional dependencies, and join dependencies. But heading is a set of free variables from the matching *predicate*. Dependencies are simply formalized notation of *constraints*. So what does it take? *Predicate* and the matching *set of constraints*, that is all. How much data, how many rows? None, not a single tuple (row) is needed. It is good to have few samples to make sure we understand constraints properly, but not necessary. Focusing on sample data is a huge mistake. Relvar (table) is in a specific NF for any set of valid tuples (rows), empty set included. It should not change NF as data keeps streaming in, if implemented properly. The NF is determined on logical design level, way before SQL `CREATE TABLE` is executed.

Comment: Being all key does not imply 5NF. If a table is always the join of two one-column components on A & B, it is all key but clearly is not in 5NF or 4NF because it satisfies the JD *{{A},{B}}. And as shown for this value in my appendix. All-key follows from only trivial FDs holding. But there can still be non-trivial JDs holding. PS Your last paragraph is not helpful. It is just a bunch of fuzzy non-technical terms--"simple", "elementary", "facts", "information" that don't explain or justify. What matters is FDs & JDs, and FDs come with JDs, and JDs come with ANDs.

Comment: @philipxy, All-key implies BCNF, as I clearly stated. Being in 5NF and all-key means 6NF. The reasoning is in steps 1-2-3. The term "simple predicate" in context of 6th NF is used by C.J. Date in *Database Design and Relational Theory*; term "elementary fact" by Terry Halpin, Tony Morgan in *Information Modeling and Relational Databases*. Who am I to argue?

Comment: Point 2 is wrong, since it unsoundly & wrongly says BCNF & all-key implies 5NF, per my answer & comment. (And it doesn't follow from your comment's first 2 sentences.) The terms as used in those books, which you do not use as they do, if made precise in terms of table predicates & tuples bear out what I have said. And clearly your "person named Oli Seitz is assigned ticket number 1" can be expressed as "there is a person named Oli Seitz AND person named Oli Seitz is assigned ticket number 1" (ie T = Person join T) so your notions of "simple" are confused. I repeat myself.

Comment: @philipxy Point 2  states that: *it is in BCNF* and *not possible to reduce redundancy by decomposition* hence in 5 NF. Anyway, I argue that *logically* your JD `*{{Ticket, Vname}, {Vname, Nname}, {Ticket, Nname}}` *does not hold* because `{Vname, Nname}` is *identifer* for the person.

Comment: You claim we "can't reduce redundancy" which I guess is your vague way of saying we can't losslessly decompose. For that *value*, we can, as I showed. For a variable, it depends on whether my JD holds in all states, which you don't mention. Re "identifier" this is irrelevant to normalization (only FDs & JDs matter) and if you are saying something nonsensical like that it seems pointless to continue. This has gone on enough anyway. (Suggest if you want clear presentations you look at the Alice book Foundations of Databases or Date's Normalization & All That Jazz.)

Comment: @philipxy Consider what would happen to your answer if you were to insert a row `(1, 'Tim', 'Seitz')`? My answer would not change. The *table* is in the **6th NF**.

Comment: Your quote for the condition for the 3-way JD to hold, expressed in terms of predicates, is wrong. I already explained the right condition in a comment. Again: Say the original's predicate is "T is assigned to F L". The component predicates are "T is assigned to person with first name F & some last name", "some ticket is assigned to F L" & "T is assigned to person with some first name & last name L". The JD says FORALL T, F, L [(AND of those 3) IFF (original's)]. The leftward implication is trivial. So it's FORALL T, F, L [IF (AND of those 3) THEN (original's)].

Comment: PS In terms of clear informal language: Assuming all people have first & last names & "that" refers back to "a certain" but not "some" & we are implicity universally quantifying, the JD says IF a certain ticket is assigned to a person with a certain first name AND some ticket is assigned to a person with that first name and a certain last name AND that ticket is assigned to a person with that last name THEN that ticket is assigned to a person with that first name & that last name". You're missing the "some ticket". Maybe you meant to say "there exists" *a ticket assigned to* "a person...".

Comment: The question doesn't make clear whether the JD holds in that value or in a variable that can hold that value. In either case we do know that the JD holds in the value. That says nothing about any other value. If we were told that the JD held in the variable then your update wouldn't be a valid value for the variable because by definition the JD holding is the same thing as its projections joining back to it. If the appropriate constraint was declared to the DBMS, the update would be rejected for constraint violation.

Comment: See my last comment on the question from when you first mentioned inserting. It says what I just commented. (Seems I forgot to @ you.)

Comment: @philipxy Try this: 1. Find (create) a table `T {A,B,C}` for which *you are certain* that is in 6th NF and can not be decomposed. 2.Then apply your reasoning to `a)` empty table and `b)` table with exactly one row. In both cases `a` and `b` you can claim that `JD *{{A,B}{B,C},{A,C}}` holds and suddenly  that table is not in 6th NF any more? Contradiction.

Comment: I don't know what point you are trying to make or what it has to do with your post or our comments. A variable is in 6NF when/iff, per the business rules & the consequent business situations that can arise & the consequent DB states that can arise, there's no non-trivial JD that it always satisfies; ie for every non-trivial JD expressible via its attributes some value can arise that doesn't satisfy it. Some but not all values satisfying the same JD does not imply 6NF. I will read the edited version of your post. I'll also check my comments & post in case I accidentally phrased things wrongly.

Comment: Part of what you seem to be trying to say, unclearly, is that a value violating a NF doesn't imply that a variable holding that value violates that NF--and that would be correct. But I repeat: 1. the question does not say whether it is talking about just that value or a variable that can hold that value; 2. you make wrong, unclear & irrelevant claims & justifications; 3. everything I've written on this page is correct.